# Strange problem about minimal and maximal elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

I have the following problem:

Let $X=\{2, 3, 4, 5, \ldots\}$ be ordered by division, that is:

$$x\leq y\Leftrightarrow x\mid y,$$
and let $\mathcal{S}=\{(A, \leq_A): A\subset X\}$ where $\leq_A$ is the order induced on $A$ by $\leq$ via restriction. Then we can order $\mathcal{S}$ via inclusion, that is:

$$A\leq_{\mathcal{S}} B\Leftrightarrow A\subset B.$$

Find the minimal and maximal elements of $\mathcal{S}$ via $\leq_{\mathcal{S}}$.

What I don't understand about this problem is: why should one consider $\mathcal{S}$ as subsets of $X$ ordered by the induced order? I mean, why can't it just be: Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the subsets of $X$ ordered by inclusion?

The minimal elements should be the unitary sets and the maximal element should be $X$, right?

Comment: Can you give us a reference for this question?

Comment: But $\mathcal S$ is indeed ordered by inclusion. The elements of $\mathcal S$, which are subsets of $X$ are the ones which are ordered by the order induced from $X$ by inclusion. About the other question, if $\varnothing$ is an element of $\mathcal S$ (and so it seems), then it is the only minimal element; the only maximal one is $X$, as you suspected.